# Similar thing to RJS (used in Ruby on Rails) in the Java web app world?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails, there's RJS templates that help do AJAX by returning javascript code that will be executed in the client browser. How can I do a similar thing in the Java/J2EE world? Is Google Widget Toolkit similar to RJS? What options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) is the java equivalent to RJS templates.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent. GWT is great if you want to do all or most of the client side in java. Also worth checking out is [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/), which gives you remote procedure call style access to your server code.